# external html won't recognize javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small product viewer that lets a user rotate a product 360º through javascript and look at alternate images of the products. Now it starts off with a series of images that make up the 360 view wrapped in a parent div, which its self is in a main container div, so the structure looks like such,

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
     <div class="child"></div>
...
   </div>
</div>
```

So from that, using the .replace method, I'll load a new image to replace the 360 view.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#parent').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('#parent').replaceWith('<img src="screen2.png" id="img2" class="child">');
    });
});
```

Now, I'm trying to restore the original 360 view using the .load method.

```
$("#button2").click(function () {
    $('#img2').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('#content').load('external.html');
    });
});
```

Now the external.html has the same content as the original view but wont recognize the javascript that lets the 360 view work. I'm not leaving the original document or web view but not sure why its not effecting the external.html.

Any ideas or help is appreciate.

Comment: Reloading the original html won't reattach all the JavaScript event handlers that where there originally. That is probably the origin of your problem but without more code, it's hard to say.

Comment: Is `#content` an iframe?

Comment: `$('#content').load('external.html');` will create new DOM elements. You would have to bind the event handlers again to the new elements. It's not really clear what the problem is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that your 360 viewer is being bound to the elements that you are replacing.  Once you replace them with the `.replaceWith()` or `.load()`, the events are no longer bound.

Without knowing how you're calling the 360 viewer, it's hard to give you the specifics.  But basically, you'll want to do something along these lines:

```
$("#button2").click(function () {
    $('#img2').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('#content').load('external.html', function() {
            // Re-bind the 360 viewer in this function
            // Below is pseudo-code, replace with proper code
            $("#content").viewer({...};
        });
    });
});
```